# How to show entirely multiline editText in Android (partially hidden by keyboard)

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext

I've three editText, and the last is multiline.
When I click into the third, the keyboard open and only the first row of this editText multiline is shown.

I would like to make scrollable this page, so i can push Send button with the keyobard opened too.

[image: closed keyboard] [image: open keyboard]

I put all in ScrollView but there is nothing below the Send button and the Scroll doesn't work.. If i put more casual Views below Send button, this is scrollable. But is not so elegant. (i can put something white after Send button)

Comment: smoothScrollTo(x, y) after EditText has focus?

Comment: How I set x and y to work correcty in all devices?

Comment: Are you already using  `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` in the manifest?  See here: http://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility.html

Comment: @GianlucaDemarinis http://angrytools.com/android/pixelcalc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place all your views in a top level ScrollView so that the content can be scrolled when the screen is not as tall as you exepct.  It's not a good idea to assume the height of the screen for general layout purposes. Always use a ScrollView if you want your content to be scrollable on all screen sizes and orientations and keyboard states.

Comment: **This is the answer as simple as it is** I was stuck raising the keyboard programmatically while listening to `ViewTreeObserver`. Saved me.

Comment: Can you please put some more details? I am facing the same thing. Thanks.